# Is it correct to say that "sympathy" is a special case of "empathy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, differences, synonyms, logic

> **empathy** = *to understand someone else's feeling*
> **sympathy** = *to share someone's sorry/sad feeling*

In case of "empathy", one can understand someone's happy & sad feelings, while in "sympathy" it's only about sad feeling. Does it mean that "sympathy" is a special case of "empathy"?
If yes, then what's the term for the other counterpart, viz. to share/feel someone's happy feeling?

**Related**:

- [How can empathy be distinguished from sympathy?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343402/how-can-empathy-be-distinguished-from-sympathy)
- [Does sympathy necessarily mean pity?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/does-sympathy-necessarily-mean-pity)

Comment: This is debated regularly by philosophers.

Comment: If you read the linked questions, you'll see people disagree on the precise meanings of the terms. With that in mind, it's impossible to unambiguously establish their relationship.